# mysqli transaction with both prepared statement and multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysqli-multi-query

I'm facing a strange issue with a transaction, this is the code:

```
$mysqli = $this->getMysqli();
    //Avoid Autocommitting
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);       
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $insertStatment = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$this->table.' (name, applied_at) VALUES (?, NOW())');
    try
    {    
        $mysqli->multi_query($sql);
        $insertStatment->bind_param('s', $name);
        $insertStatment->execute();
        $insertStatment->close();
        $mysqli->commit();
        $mysqli->close();
        return TRUE;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      $mysqli->rollBack();
      return $e->getMessage(); 
    }
```

The $insertStatement gets completely ignored by the commit(). If I comment this line:

```
$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

It works perfectly, is there any issue when mixing prepared statements and multi_query?
I need multi query because the `$sql` variable contains multiple `;` separated sql statements. Is there any way to prevent this issue?

Comment: I think that's the reason multi_query is created.